# What is a Bootstrap disabled button hover class name?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dom

On my site I have a disabled button. After hover event it changes a color for a wrong one.

I want to change a hover colour for this button and I can't find / don't know what is a class name disabled button hover in the bootstrap framework for this issue.

Exmaple is:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">My disabled button</button>
```

Comment: what is the problem here? why is your `disabled` class outside the class list?

Comment: Could it be that you have a css definition overriding the default disabled-hover-background?

Comment: @GurtejSingh that is an attribute, not class name

Comment: @JonesVinothJoseph My bad. I thought he meant to add the disabled class.

Comment: @Gurtej Singh I want to change this disabled button background colour in hover event. Default bootstrap colur is blue one ...

Answer (score 2):

These are the two types of disabled button you can make with bootstrap:

1.Disabled UI, but not the button itself [use the class `disabled`] (try clicking the button in the snippet)

2.Button disabled | Bootstrap applies the disabled effect here by default. [or use both: the attribute and the `disabled` class].

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary disabled" onclick="alert('not actaully disabled');">My disabled button</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled onclick="alert('not actaully disabled');">My disabled button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.btn-default[disabled] {
background: #ccc !important;
}
.btn-default[disabled]:hover {
background: #ccc !important;
}
```

I'm using this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. 
I've found right class name for this issue.

Just put

```
.btn[disabled]:hover {
    background:#bedd16;
    }

.btn[disabled]:active:focus { 
    color: #000000;
    }

.btn[disabled]:focus { 
    background: #bedd16;
    color: #666666;
    }
```

for change a disabled button hover backgroud ... ;)

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap have disable class in button
you can use like this

```
    <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" disabled>

CSS

input[disabled] {
    cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

No any javascript need for button disable.

Comment: This wont disable the button actually.. It will just add the disabled effect, i.e.: button will still be clickable !

Comment: Just add Small css in your code input[disabled] {
    cursor:not-allowed;
}

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior of any browser ? You just need to add the `disabled` attribute to the button mate `:)`