# Disable button color change when mouse hover over button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to disable button color change when mouse hover over button or user push the button?

I'm using bootstrap:

```
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

And here is some part of code that use button:

```
<form id="idForm1" method="post" action="/web_crawler">
    <h4> Web crawler requests: </h4><br>
    <textarea id="id_text_requests" name="text" rows="5" cols="20" style="resize:none">{{text_requests}}</textarea><br>
    <input id="form1_send_button" type="button" class="btn" value="Run web crawler">
    <br>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**

Base on answers and suggestions, here is (not perfect) solution with css, but I hardcoded color(maybe it can be done in some automated way?) and also after button is in clicked state some dotted frame appears, how to remove it?

Here example:

```
.btn:hover {
    background:#325d88;
    }
.btn:active:focus { 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
.btn:focus { 
    background: #325d88;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

Looks like it was [firefox related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links):

This can fix it:

```
.btn:focus { 
    background: #325d88;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline:none;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I think it's best if you use a custom button because bootstrap does all that styling every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Bootstrap disabled button hover class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343575/what-is-a-bootstrap-disabled-button-hover-class-name)

Comment: **You can do it with css ** [Click here to see the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750078/style-disabled-button-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

Create a style of disabled button in every states: `:disabled`, `:hover`, `:active`

```
.btn:disabled,
.btn:disabled:hover,
.btn:disabled:active,
.btn:disabled:hover:active {
    // Your disabled styles
}
```

**Live Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/565ang1z/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css

```
#idForm1    .btn:focus,
#idForm1    .btn:active:focus,
#idForm1    .btn.active:focus,
#idForm1    .btn.focus,
#idForm1    .btn:active.focus,
#idForm1    .btn.active.focus {
  outline: none;
  outline-offset: 0;
}
#idForm1    .btn:hover,
#idForm1    .btn:focus,
#idForm1    .btn.focus {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#idForm1    .btn:active,
#idForm1    .btn.active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```